# JSON remove objects which DO NOT contain

Tags: python, json

I process JSON data and want to remove unnecessary objects.
Objects which "message" key DO NOT contain *["vente" or "sell" or "achat" or "buy" and "zonedentr"] OR ["pipsclture" or "pipscloture" or "pipclture" or "pipcloture"] OR ["fermer le trade" or "fermez le trade"] OR ["modifier sl"]*

Here's the code I've come with:

```
import json

# Load the JSON data
with open("Telegram_Msg.json", "r") as file:
    data_dict = json.load(file)

# Filter out unnecessary objects
data_dict = [d for d in data_dict if "message" in d and (
    (("vente" in d["message"] or "sell" in d["message"] or "achat" in d["message"] or "buy" in d["message"]) and "zonedentr" in d["message"]) or
    ("pipsclture" in d["message"] or "pipscloture" in d["message"] or "pipclture" in d["message"] or "pipcloture" in d["message"]) or
    ("fermer le trade" in d["message"] or "fermez le trade" in d["message"]) or
    "modifier sl" in d["message"]
)]

# Reorganize the data
# ...

# Export data to new JSON file
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data_dict, f, indent=4)
```

But it doesn't work.
Instead of removing the unnecessary objects not containing specific text, it removes everything the output.json file is empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to have all unnecessary values in a list and use `all` to filter them:

```
to_remove = [
    "vente", "sell", "achat", "buy", "zonedentr",
    "pipsclture", "pipscloture", "pipclture", "pipcloture",
    "fermer le trade", "fermez le trade",
    "modifier sl"
]

data_dict = [
    d for d in data_dict 
    if "message" not in d or all(r not in d['message'] for r in to_remove)
]
```